# TFS: Best way to deploy to remote web server

Tags: deployment, tfs, azure-pipelines, vpn

we have a TFS 2018 running inside our Intranet and want to deploy to a remote machine outside of our intranet. The TFS is not visible from the outside (behind Firewall and does not have its own IP)
So we came up with this solution, that might work:

1. Set up a VPN connection between the target machine and our intranet
2. Create an Azure Pipeline Agent on the target machine that uses a private access token to communicate to the TFS

Is there an easier solution to this, which doesn't require a VPN connection?
We thought we could deploy to a web share from TFS and then trigger the Azure Pipeline Agent on the target machine, to start the deployment. But from the [documentation of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) it seems as if the Agent has to have direct access to the TFS trough HTTPS and only "listens" to jobs in the TFS queue.

That means that the only other solution to a VPN connection from the target machine would be, to make our TFS accessible from the internet trough HTTPS, right?

Unfortunately, until now we haven't found a lot of documentation on "best practices" for this use case. That's why I decided to share it here. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ You could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment) to configure TFS for Web Deployment. You could check it and then kindly share the result here. If I misunderstood you, could you please describe your question in more detail? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, I read through the tutorial. Our issue is best described by the task "Manually Installing Web Packages" here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/manually-installing-web-packages
But this is the TFS 2010 way of doing it. We want to use an Azure Dev Ops Pipeline to do the same: Deploy to a production server outside our intranet.
Until now we know, that the production server has to have "line of sight" to the TFS Server in order to pull deployment packages via HTTPS and deploy them to its local IIS.

Comment: So the question is: Do we make our Build Server visible from the Internet (Having its own IP-adress and opening the required ports. We think that's a bad idea) or do we open a VPN tunel from our production servers to the Intranet so the deployment agent on the prod server can communicate with the TFS in our Intranet via HTTPS.
AND are these our own two options? Isn't there a "Watch a file share"-deployment agent that deploys packages automatically, as soon as we send them to this share?